# Exception when parsing date

Tags: java, parsing, date

I am trying to parse a date in Java,

- Date example: `Mon, 12 Jan 2015 11:46:05 GMT`
- String format: `EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z`

But I get an exception:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon, 12 Jan 2015 11:57:13 GMT"

Comment: Post the code and the stacktrace of the exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the locale when creating `SimpleDateFormat` instance:

```
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SimpleDateFormat With Joda DateTime Object:::

```
    try{
    String date = "Mon, 12 Jan 2015 11:46:05 GMT";
    String format = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z";

    SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(SDF.parse(date)) ;
        System.out.println(" Date :: " + dateTime.toString());
    }catch (ParseException pex)
    {
        pex.printStackTrace();
    }
```